Wildcard/regexp query with asterix chacter
I'm new to elasticsearch. I would write a query, that matches a document with the following attribute:
description: 20*40x555
I want the query matches with the following inputs:

20X40X555
20*40*555
20x40x555
the combination of these

I tired the wildcard, and the regex query also. If the document's attribute does not contains any asterix characters the query works fine, but when the description attribute contains an * character it does not find.
I tried with the following queries:
with wildcard:
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "short_description": "*20?40?555*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

with regexp:
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "short_description": ".*20.*40.*555.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

When the short attribute is ex 20x40x555 both of these working, but if I change the value to 20*40x555 it does not returns the document unfortunately.
How can I achieve to get results when the value of the sort_description is eg. 20*40x555 ? Thanks!

Assuming that you are using standard analyzer to index the "*" is no longer present in the index. The text 20*40x555 is indexed as two tokens 20 and 40x555. The simplest way to make * interchangeable with x is to replace it with x during the indexing operations by using patter_replace filter. Here is a simple example that illustrates this idea:
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "asterisk_to_x": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\S)\\*(\\S)",
          "replacement": "$1x$2"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": ["asterisk_to_x"],
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "short_description": {
        "type": "text", 
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{"short_description":"20x40*555"}


POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "short_description": "20X40X555"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


I ended up with the similar approach. I choose to parse the document when I create/refresh. I made a similar regex to replace the special chars which I use in the query (*, /, -), and replaced with the 'x' char. Since I only use the id of the document  I can live with that. (After the elastic query I run an sql query with the found id-s, and I only use with pagination, so it is efficient. The document in elastic contains only the searchable properties of the queried entities.) But I'll definitely try your method, thanks!

Your data (20*40x555) is not atomic. You should split it into atomic parts
Mapping
PUT /descriptions
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "short_description": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "width": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "heigth": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "depth": {
                "type": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample documents
PUT /descriptions/_bulk?refresh
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"short_description": "20*40x555"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"short_description": "20X40X555"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"short_description": "20*40*555"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"short_description": "20x40x555"}

Query with a simplified script to split short_description into atomic parts
POST /descriptions/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": """
            String shortDescription = ctx["_source"]["short_description"];
            String[] dimension = /[*xX]/.split(shortDescription);
            ctx["_source"]["width"] = Long.parseLong(dimension[0]);
            ctx["_source"]["heigth"] = Long.parseLong(dimension[1]);
            ctx["_source"]["depth"] = Long.parseLong(dimension[2]);
        """
    }
}

Now you could search data by a precise query
GET /descriptions/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "width": {
                            "value": 20
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "heigth": {
                            "value": 40
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "depth": {
                            "value": 555
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

or by a range query
GET /descriptions/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "width": {
                            "gte": 15,
                            "lte": 24
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "heigth": {
                            "gte": 30,
                            "lte": 50
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "depth": {
                            "gte": 500,
                            "lte": 600
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

